# Xcp 2.1 Preview mode error

Tags: documentum, webby

When I am trying to run the preview mode in Xcp 2.1 . I am getting the below error.

> http://localhost:8888/Concordant_Insurance/reloadcontext?webby
>
> HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /Concordant_Insurance/reloadcontext.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Powered by Jetty://

Also , when I checked the xCP designer logs i am seeing the below.

```
2015-09-21T11:02:01.894  INFO [Tmain] [com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection:377] Object protocol version 2
2015-09-21T11:02:02.519  INFO [Tmain] [com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.AuthenticationMgr:448] new identity bundle <dfc_m0m14WKi50bKqjX3rBVf33lcIuca  1442813522  SYNPSZD4515.syntelorg.com       aKqqpudgiie/TVVX5nqwOeOWKMSSD3W19n1LkWPftu/4ahAW5E+iLN7LsrTgjpcgLuVaNMex7jb64Cgupy+KitzI/liMqlEWY8iQqa2kDsFO3x7uzjqAnF+FYqIvinHg0sjw7Z1mTqdAzUJiFmNzRcYzyeaRHPE/cFyB0WzW4VY=>
2015-09-21T11:03:45.821  INFO [Tmain] [com.documentum.deployment.service.DeploymentManager:113] Catalog path is set to: [/C:/Users/NT5023515/Desktop/Documentum self Doc/xCPDesigner/plugins/com.emc.ide.external.dfc_2.0.0.201502150958//deploymentCatalog/]
2015-09-21T11:05:02.910  INFO [Tmain] [com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection:377] Object protocol version 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the **`target`** folder located inside your `Application workspace`